# My picturebox arrays create Null References Visual Basic

Tags: .net, arrays, picturebox

So I have picture boxes that I have put into an array, however when I run my program I get the error of a `NullReferenceExecption` being unhandled.

```
 Dim ground(5) As PictureBox

 ground(0) = Ground1
 ground(1) = Ground2
 ground(2) = Ground3
 ground(3) = Ground4
 ground(4) = Ground5
 ground(5) = Ground6
```

Then later in a timer,

```
 For ss = 0 To 4
        If StopH.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ground(ss).Bounds) Or CrouchH.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ground(ss).Bounds) Or JumpH.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ground(ss).Bounds) Or RunningH.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ground(ss).Bounds) Then

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What are `StopH`, `CrouchH`, `JumpH`, and `RunningH`?  Do they have non-null values?

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is .net lingo - are you sure this is VBA? Or rather, are you sure it's not a *runtime error 91*?

Comment: ah sorry. Those are all pictureboxes that I am trying to find collision for.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sorry. I might have mislabeled this. I'll go and fix it, I am doing this for a school project so I am not overly familiar with everything.